# Kafka SSL connection failure on handshake

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka

Kafka client cannot connect to server via SSL connection for some reason. It goes through SSL handshake, I can see it in the client trace log, but then occasionally fails with "disconnected" message. Looks like Kafka server closes the connection after receives Client Hello.

It fails only when I try it from the OpenShift environment. The same build, configuration settings and SSL certificates work when I'm trying to connect from my local developer machine. Tools like OffsetExplorer are also able to connect from my local PC.

I'm trying to understand what can be different in terms of SSL between OpenShift and my local PC.

Here is the log I grep by KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#5-0-C-1 thread:

```
    Line 93734: 2022-05-24 11:10:26,409 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#5-0-C-1] [TRACE] (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) [org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient::leastLoadedNode:722] mdc:()| [Consumer clientId=ADCAB-0, groupId=ADCAB_GROUP] Found least loaded node 10.53.15.97:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) with no active connection
    Line 93735: 2022-05-24 11:10:26,409 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#5-0-C-1] [DEBUG] (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) [org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater::maybeUpdate:1176] mdc:()| [Consumer clientId=ADCAB-0, groupId=ADCAB_GROUP] Initialize connection to node 10.53.15.97:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) for sending metadata request
    Line 93736: 2022-05-24 11:10:26,409 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#5-0-C-1] [DEBUG] (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) [org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient::initiateConnect:1005] mdc:()| [Consumer clientId=ADCAB-0, groupId=ADCAB_GROUP] Initiating connection to node 10.53.15.97:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) using address /10.53.15.97
    Line 93736: 2022-05-24 11:10:26,409 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#5-0-C-1] [DEBUG] (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) [org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient::initiateConnect:1005] mdc:()| [Consumer clientId=ADCAB-0, groupId=ADCAB_GROUP] Initiating connection to node 10.53.15.97:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) using address /10.53.15.97
    Line 94113: 2022-05-24 11:10:27,386 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#5-0-C-1] [TRACE] (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer) [org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer::doHandshake:339] mdc:()| [SslTransportLayer channelId=-1 key=channel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/10.53.15.97:9093], selector=sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@41c9572a, interestOps=8, readyOps=0] SSLHandshake NEED_WRAP channelId -1, appReadBuffer pos 0, netReadBuffer pos 0, netWriteBuffer pos 0
    Line 94115: 2022-05-24 11:10:27,386 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#5-0-C-1] [TRACE] (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer) [org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer::handshakeWrap:472] mdc:()| [SslTransportLayer channelId=-1 key=channel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/10.53.15.97:9093], selector=sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@41c9572a, interestOps=8, readyOps=0] SSLHandshake handshakeWrap -1
    Line 94117: 2022-05-24 11:10:27,386 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#5-0-C-1] [TRACE] (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer) [org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer::doHandshake:356] mdc:()| [SslTransportLayer channelId=-1 key=channel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/10.53.15.97:9093], selector=sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@41c9572a, interestOps=8, readyOps=0] SSLHandshake NEED_WRAP channelId -1, handshakeResult Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NEED_UNWRAP
    Line 94122: 2022-05-24 11:10:27,387 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#5-0-C-1] [TRACE] (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer) [org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer::doHandshake:365] mdc:()| [SslTransportLayer channelId=-1 key=channel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/10.53.15.97:9093], selector=sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@41c9572a, interestOps=8, readyOps=0] SSLHandshake NEED_UNWRAP channelId -1, appReadBuffer pos 0, netReadBuffer pos 0, netWriteBuffer pos 307
    Line 94124: 2022-05-24 11:10:27,387 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#5-0-C-1] [TRACE] (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer) [org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer::handshakeUnwrap:499] mdc:()| [SslTransportLayer channelId=-1 key=channel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/10.53.15.97:9093], selector=sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@41c9572a, interestOps=8, readyOps=0] SSLHandshake handshakeUnwrap -1
    Line 94126: 2022-05-24 11:10:27,387 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#5-0-C-1] [TRACE] (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer) [org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer::handshakeUnwrap:519] mdc:()| [SslTransportLayer channelId=-1 key=channel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/10.53.15.97:9093], selector=sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@41c9572a, interestOps=8, readyOps=0] SSLHandshake handshakeUnwrap: handshakeStatus NEED_UNWRAP status BUFFER_UNDERFLOW
    Line 94128: 2022-05-24 11:10:27,387 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#5-0-C-1] [TRACE] (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer) [org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer::doHandshake:387] mdc:()| [SslTransportLayer channelId=-1 key=channel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/10.53.15.97:9093], selector=sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@41c9572a, interestOps=8, readyOps=0] SSLHandshake NEED_UNWRAP channelId -1, handshakeResult Status = BUFFER_UNDERFLOW HandshakeStatus = NEED_UNWRAP
    Line 94134: 2022-05-24 11:10:27,387 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#5-0-C-1] [TRACE] (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) [org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient::leastLoadedNode:719] mdc:()| [Consumer clientId=ADCAB-0, groupId=ADCAB_GROUP] Found least loaded connecting node 10.53.15.97:9093 (id: -1 rack: null)
    Line 94137: 2022-05-24 11:10:27,388 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#5-0-C-1] [TRACE] (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer) [org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer::doHandshake:365] mdc:()| [SslTransportLayer channelId=-1 key=channel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/10.53.15.97:9093], selector=sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@41c9572a, interestOps=8, readyOps=0] SSLHandshake NEED_UNWRAP channelId -1, appReadBuffer pos 0, netReadBuffer pos 0, netWriteBuffer pos 307
    Line 94139: 2022-05-24 11:10:27,388 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#5-0-C-1] [TRACE] (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer) [org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer::handshakeUnwrap:499] mdc:()| [SslTransportLayer channelId=-1 key=channel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/10.53.15.97:9093], selector=sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@41c9572a, interestOps=8, readyOps=0] SSLHandshake handshakeUnwrap -1
    Line 94141: 2022-05-24 11:10:27,388 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#5-0-C-1] [TRACE] (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer) [org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer::handshakeUnwrap:519] mdc:()| [SslTransportLayer channelId=-1 key=channel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/10.53.15.97:9093], selector=sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@41c9572a, interestOps=8, readyOps=0] SSLHandshake handshakeUnwrap: handshakeStatus NEED_UNWRAP status BUFFER_UNDERFLOW
    Line 94143: 2022-05-24 11:10:27,388 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#5-0-C-1] [TRACE] (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer) [org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer::handshakeUnwrap:499] mdc:()| [SslTransportLayer channelId=-1 key=channel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/10.53.15.97:9093], selector=sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@41c9572a, interestOps=8, readyOps=0] SSLHandshake handshakeUnwrap -1
    Line 94145: 2022-05-24 11:10:27,388 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#5-0-C-1] [TRACE] (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer) [org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer::handshakeUnwrap:519] mdc:()| [SslTransportLayer channelId=-1 key=channel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/10.53.15.97:9093], selector=sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@41c9572a, interestOps=8, readyOps=0] SSLHandshake handshakeUnwrap: handshakeStatus NEED_UNWRAP status BUFFER_UNDERFLOW
    Line 94148: 2022-05-24 11:10:27,388 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#5-0-C-1] [DEBUG] (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector) [org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector::pollSelectionKeys:606] mdc:()| [Consumer clientId=ADCAB-0, groupId=ADCAB_GROUP] Connection with /10.53.15.97 disconnected
    Line 94178: 2022-05-24 11:10:27,389 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#5-0-C-1] [DEBUG] (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer) [org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer::close:198] mdc:()| [SslTransportLayer channelId=-1 key=channel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/10.53.15.97:9093], selector=sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@41c9572a, interestOps=8, readyOps=0] Failed to send SSL Close message
    Line 94208: 2022-05-24 11:10:27,390 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#5-0-C-1] [WARN] (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) [org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient::processDisconnection:775] mdc:()| [Consumer clientId=ADCAB-0, groupId=ADCAB_GROUP] Connection to node -1 (/10.53.15.97:9093) terminated during authentication. This may happen due to any of the following reasons: (1) Authentication failed due to invalid credentials with brokers older than 1.0.0, (2) Firewall blocking Kafka TLS traffic (eg it may only allow HTTPS traffic), (3) Transient network issue.
    Line 94210: 2022-05-24 11:10:27,390 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#5-0-C-1] [WARN] (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) [org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater::handleServerDisconnect:1079] mdc:()| [Consumer clientId=ADCAB-0, groupId=ADCAB_GROUP] Bootstrap broker 10.53.15.97:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

And here is the listener configuration:

```
2022-05-24 11:10:23,199 [main] [INFO] (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig) [org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig::logAll:361] mdc:()| ConsumerConfig values: 
    allow.auto.create.topics = true
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = latest
    bootstrap.servers = [10.53.15.97:9093, 10.53.15.96:9093]
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = ADCAB-0
    client.rack = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = false
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = ADCAB_GROUP
    group.instance.id = null
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    internal.throw.on.fetch.stable.offset.unsupported = false
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 500
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = SSL
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 10000
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 127000
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = 
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = [hidden]
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
    ssl.keystore.key = null
    ssl.keystore.location = /opt/keystore/kafka/sbercms/kafka_keystore.jks
    ssl.keystore.password = [hidden]
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.certificates = null
    ssl.truststore.location = /opt/keystore/kafka/sbercms/kafka_truststore.jks
    ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class ru.sberbank.pprb.sbbol.adcab.utils.kafka.LoggingJsonDeserializer
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there was an environment problem with the SSL certificates. DevOps managed to resolve it.